# Is there a way to configure email account on iPhone from code?

Tags: iphone

I'm quite new in iPhone development. I'm interested to configure email account on iPhone from code. Is it possible? Is there any API in SDK to implement this?

Thank in advance for your answers.

Regards,
M. Wolniewicz

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot configure eMail accounts on an unjailbroken iPhone from code.